# Is there any difference between "go over something" and "go back over something" in the sense of reviewing something?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between *go over something* and *go back over something* in the sense of reviewing something? For example:

> If you want to pass the exam, you had better **go over** what you have gone through so far.

> If you want to pass the exam, you had better **go back over** what you have gone through so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a small difference of emphasis. When you "go over" something, you examine it. When you "go back over" something, you examine it again.

Looking specifically at the given context, if you are about to have an exam on something, you will have seen the material before, so saying that you should "go over" it means that you are to examine it again.

If you are examining it again, why not just say "go back over"? Saying "go **back** over" underlines or emphasizes the repetition.